# Auth0 redirect to localhost is blocked by the browser

Tags: flutter, windows, desktop-application, auth0

I have a Windows application written by Flutter. I use Auth0 to handle the login/logout stuff. Unlike the macOS application, Windows app can not redirect directly from the browser, so I created a local server in my application to handle the auth0 callback. It works fine in the debug mode. However, it doesn't work when I build in the release version by the command `flutter build windows --release`.

After I entered the account and the password, the browser blocked the redirection like the image below.
[image]

I am guessing it's the cookies security issue. It's a really weird problem that it works fine in the debug mode but does not work in the release version.

Below is the part of my code:

```
login() async {
  final url = Uri.https(auth0Uri, '/authorize', {
     'client_id': clientId,
     'audience': audience,
     'response_type': 'code',
     'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
  });

  launchUrl(url);

  await HttpServer.bind('localhost', 39456);

  await for (var request in localServer!) {
    handleRequest(request);
  }
}


handleRequest(HttpRequest request) {
  Uri uri = request.uri;

  // Get queryParameters from uri
  Map<String, String> queryParams = uri.queryParameters;

  // Get code
  String? code = queryParams['code'];

  debugPrint('code: $code');

  request.response.write("OK");

  request.response.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

Verify Certificate Handling:
Ensure that your HTTPS server (local server) is using a valid SSL certificate. In release mode, security restrictions might be stricter, and a self-signed certificate or an invalid certificate could cause issues.

Change http Instead of https for Local Server:
Since this is a local server for authentication purposes, you might try using HTTP instead of HTTPS during development. In a production environment, you would want to use HTTPS, but for local testing, HTTP might be sufficient.